# Hi I have a problem using a while loop with matlab

Tags: matlab

I have a problem using a while loop. My main objective is to simulate a fanno flow problem when for a case where the length of the tube is longer than require. this means we have to change the mach number in the middle. my code is the following.

clc
clear all
close all

P1=1;
T1=273;
Cf=0.005;
Dh=0.15;
G=1.4;
M1=3.0;

Lxstar=0;
M2=1;
Lx=0;
My=0;
Lystar=0;
tol=.001;
L = 6.0;
error=0;

fp = ((1-M1^2)/(G*M1^2))+((G+1)/(2*G))*log(((G+1)*M1^2)/(2*(1+(M1^2*(G-1)/(2)))))

Lstar=(fp*Dh)./(4*Cf)

```
while Lstar<L
    Mx=(M1+M2)./2


    fp1=((1-Mx^2)/(G*Mx^2))+((G+1)/(2*G))*log(((G+1)*Mx^2)/(2*(1+(Mx^2*(G-1)/(2)))))

    Lxstar= (fp1*Dh)./(4*Cf)
    Lx= Lstar-Lxstar
    My=((sqrt((2+(G-1)*Mx.^2)/(2*G*Mx.^2-(G-1)))));
    fp2=((1-My^2)/(G*My^2))+((G+1)/(2*G))*log(((G+1)*My^2)/(2*(1+(My^2*(G-1)/(2)))))

    Lystar=(fp2*Dh)./(4*Cf)
   error= Lx+Lystar-L
   if error<=tol
       break

   else
       Diff=Lx+Lystar
       if Diff<L
           Mx=Mx+.01
       else
           Mx=Mx-.01
       end
   end
end
```

When i run it goes smoothly it does everything i want but once it changes the Mx it runs again with the Mx=M1+M2/2 instead of the corrected Mx = Mx+.01 or Mx= Mx-.01

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pull the assignment of Mx out of the loop. It is being reassigned every time.

```
Mx=(M1+M2)./2
while Lstar<L



    fp1=((1-Mx^2)/(G*Mx^2))+((G+1)/(2*G))*log(((G+1)*Mx^2)/(2*(1+(Mx^2*(G-1)/(2)))))

    Lxstar= (fp1*Dh)./(4*Cf)
    Lx= Lstar-Lxstar
    My=((sqrt((2+(G-1)*Mx.^2)/(2*G*Mx.^2-(G-1)))));
    fp2=((1-My^2)/(G*My^2))+((G+1)/(2*G))*log(((G+1)*My^2)/(2*(1+(My^2*(G-1)/(2)))))

    Lystar=(fp2*Dh)./(4*Cf)
   error= Lx+Lystar-L
   if error<=tol
       break

   else
       Diff=Lx+Lystar
       if Diff<L
           Mx=Mx+.01
       else
           Mx=Mx-.01
       end
   end
end
```

Comment: Okay thanks that's what I just realized too. It seems to work now. Thanks

Comment: Again thank you so much.

Comment: Anytime. That sort of problem happens all the time, glad it helped.

Comment: its printing everything out how do i tell it to only print the last iteration? i added ";" but it still prints all iterations

Comment: I wouldn't know without the latest version. All I can think is that there is some line that didn't get a semicolon. Did you find anything?

Comment: It worked! I don't know what I did lol.